# Test the existence of User/System DSN in XPages

Tags: javascript, odbc, xpages, lotus-domino

in my xpage I have an editbox for user to enter the name of the ODBC data source. Then onBlur I want to test whether the user entered value is valid/exist in the ODBC list. If there is error/exception, I want the error to be displayed in a 'Display Error' control I have in the xpage. I'm not sure where to start. Never done something like this before(even in LotusScript). Somebody enlighten me please?

Comment: Not sure what your end deployment senario is, but this is screaming out injection attack. I would highly recommend you look at the ExtLib JDBC tools rather than trying to roll your own connection, let alone allow your web user the ability to query what DSNs exist on your server then potentially post to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently this is what I need. Maybe I should polish my question asking skill. Thanks to those who help though.

Referring to [here](http://kramkumarmca.blogspot.com/2012/01/odbc-in-xpages-javascript.html), I create 3 field/editbox: 'ODBC/DSN Name', 'username', 'password'. For 'ODBC/DSN Name', I put an xp:validateExpression and put the following code for the expression part:

```
var odbc:string=getComponent("inputText1").getValueAsString();
var url:string="jdbc:odbc:"+odbc;
var usr:string=getComponent("inputText2").getValueAsString();
var pwd:string=getComponent("inputText3").getValueAsString();
try {
    java.lang.Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    var con:java.sql.Connection=java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url,usr,pwd);
    return true;
} catch (e) {
    return false;
}
```

Not sure whether I utilized the xp:validateExpression or xpages itself the right way but that's what customer request and seems to be working now.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't do that in an onBlur event. Your user might want to change something else and you hit her with a slow operation. What you should do:

- have a test button
- gray out the "save" button until the test was successful

In any case: have a look at the extension library. It has the RDBMS connectivity build in (use it, don't reinvent the wheel). Copy the code from there.

Comment: don't forget to reset test status to unsuccessful on any change to entered data.

Answer (score -1):

Better to write in onchange event of the item that you need to validate. Because we usually do the partial refresh for that event right? So It prevents the item from entering the value.

Simply try to write that in onchange event. But my opinion is that I used to write the validations for non- secure items in Jquery. Because that is very easy and gives nice outlook.

Comment: I would say:bad idea. A onChange event for a text box fires on every letter. So until you are finished typing a 40 char connection string - you have 39 failed attempts

Comment: But onchange event will trigger only if we change the cursor to another item. whatever character by character it won't trigger. I guess that It is not onchange of the value of that item. It is the onchange the positioning the item. If I did wrong., Please correct me., Thanks stwissel.